# What happend to Nymeria?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones*, on S7E2 we saw that Nymeria and Arya had a reunion. Nymeria was with her own pack of wolves and refuses to go along with Arya. Nymeria did not appear in S8 anywhere.

So what happened to the Direwolf? Is there any mention of it in the books? Do they meet again when Arya voyages around?

Comment: Since the books aren't finished yet, we'll have to wait and see if things play out differently.

Answer (score 8):

After Nymeria leaves Arya, she becomes the leader of a huge wolf pack in the Riverlands. She and her brother Ghost are now the only living Stark dire wolves.
As per the books, Nymeria is said to be leading a pack of wolves that do not fear men. She refuses Arya's invitation to go home with her and returns with her pack to the forest.

Answer (score 1):

In order to save Nymeria from Joffrey, Arya Stark throws a stone at her and makes her leave. For quite a long time, Nymeria's status remains unknown. However, in the S7E2 Nymeria and Arya have a "reunion". Nymeria has become an Alpha (leader) wolf of a pack in the Riverlands.

When they meet again, Nymeria "orders" the rest of the wolves to not attack her. This action shows that the bond and affection between Nymeria and Arya are still strong. Many fans would like for Arya and Nymeria to reconciliate -basically for Nymeria to abandon her pack and follow Arya-, however, it is important to understand that Nymeria has changed. She still loves Arya, but has changed and won't just go back to following her. What most of you probably never thought of is that she would most probably have children of her own now (considering her age) and ties to other wolves which all would be too much to give away in order to return to Arya.